# Error in Time difference between server and local system

Tags: java, time

I am capturing the object create time. In local system it displays the correct creattime but whenever the code runs on server it is displaying wrong time with difference of 4-5 hrs.
However, the difference between server and my local system is only 2 mins.
Here is my code to capture the create time of object:---

```
object.setCreateTime(new Date());
```

Any suggestion please.

Thanks.

Comment: check system timezone of both machine

Comment: There is AFAIK no file related class in the Java Runtime which has a method named "setCreateTime(..)". Looks like you are using a 3rd party library. May be this library is buggy?

Comment: @Robert One assumes that is a setter on his business POJO

Answer (score 0):

Change the System time zone in both local system and server.